# Create custom msgBox button in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have code that searches a Google spreadsheet for any duplicate entries. When a duplicate is found, a message box pops up to tell the user. It asks the user whether he/she wants to delete the duplicate with YES and NO buttons.

That all works fine. However, ideally, instead of using YES and NO buttons, I want to have three buttons: "Delete Original," "Delete Duplicate," and "Do Not Delete (or CANCEL)," so the user can choose which one to delete.

Is there any way to create custom buttons within a message box? Or, at least, change the names of the stock YES/NO buttons, and have a CANCEL button?

**EDIT:**

Here is my HTML code to pop up a dialog box:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top"> 
    <script>
    function onSuccess(result)
    {
      var resultInfo = document.getElementById("myPara");

      resultInfo.innerHTML = result;
    } 

     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess(result)).passResultToHTML();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id = "myPara">This is the default text.</p>
    <div id = "myDiv"></div>

   <button onclick=google.script.run.deleteOriginalTitle()>Delete Original</button>
   <button onclick=google.script.run.deleteDuplicateTitle()>Delete Duplicate</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Code in the .gs:

```
 function findDuplicateTitles()
{ 
  var startRow = Browser.inputBox("At which row would you like to start the search?\\n\\n");
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("scriptTestingHTML").setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  for (var x = (startRow - 1); x < titleColumnArray.length; x++)
  {  
    currentTitle = titleColumnArray[x][0];
    var y = x + 1;

    for (y; y < titleColumnArray.length; y++)
    { 
      if (titleColumnArray[y][0] == currentTitle)
      {
        currentTitleValues = sheet.getRange(x + 1, 1, 1, 8).getDisplayValues()
        duplicateFound = true;
        duplicateCount++;
        duplicateRowNum = y + 1;
        duplicateTitleValues = sheet.getRange(duplicateRowNum, 1, 1, 8).getDisplayValues();

        //resultString is a global String
        resultString = "I found a duplicate entry \\n\\n" + 
                                   "Original Title on Row: " + (x + 1) + "\\n\\n" + 
                                   currentTitleValues[0][0] + " | " +
                                   currentTitleValues[0][1] + " | " +
                                   currentTitleValues[0][2] + " | " +
                                   currentTitleValues[0][3] + " | " +
                                   currentTitleValues[0][4] + " | " +
                                   currentTitleValues[0][5] + " | " +
                                   currentTitleValues[0][6] + " | " +
                                   currentTitleValues[0][7] + " | " + 
                                   "\\n\\n" +
                                   "Duplicate Title on Row: " + duplicateRowNum + 
                                   "\\n\\n" + 
                                   duplicateTitleValues[0][0] + " | " +
                                   duplicateTitleValues[0][1] + " | " +
                                   duplicateTitleValues[0][2] + " | " +
                                   duplicateTitleValues[0][3] + " | " +
                                   duplicateTitleValues[0][4] + " | " +
                                   duplicateTitleValues[0][5] + " | " +
                                   duplicateTitleValues[0][6] + " | " +
                                   duplicateTitleValues[0][7] + " | " +
                                   "\\n\\nDelete this duplicate? Or delete the original?";


        Logger.log(resultString);
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, "Duplicate Entry Found");

        Utilities.sleep(5000); 
      }
    } 
  }
```

After resultString is set and the dialog opens, the HTML calls this funtion:

```
function passResultToHTML()
{
  return resultString;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please follow the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is currently not possible in a standalone script. However, what you could do is make this script container-bound (AKA an add-on). Then instead of using Browser, you could use SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog()

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface-title

This will allow you to pop up a custom HTML file as a dialog box, and you can set custom responses to your buttons with Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, Ev! I looked at shoModalDialog() a little bit, but didn't get very far. I'll play around with it some more and see what happens.

Comment: Okay, I've created an HTML file for a dialog box, and I'm trying to pass a string to it containing the duplicate info. But when I call the server for it, it comes back undefined. Any thoughts?

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).passResultToHTML();

    function onSuccess(resultFromServer)
    {
      var resultInfo = document.getElementById("myPara");
           
      resultInfo.innerHTML = resultFromServer;
    }

   (passResultToHTML() simply returns the string.)

Comment: It's a little difficult to read, but I think I see your problem.

try:
`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess(result)).passResultToHTML(); `

The problem seems to be that you aren't actually picking up the returned data.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help. I apologize for the illegibility of my comment (I didn't know how to format code in a comment). I tried your suggestion, but now it seems that onSuccess() will not even run. Please see my HTML code in the edit of my original post.

Comment: Could you post your code for the .gs function. I feel like that would be what's causing the problem, and it would give me a better handle on what's actually happening.

Comment: Yeah... GAS doesn't really handle globals very well. It's very shoddy at best. Instead, cache it in either Properties or cache services.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/

So, keep your result there until, and withdraw it from your retrieval function.

Comment: EvSunWoodard, thanks very much indeed for all your help! I used Properties instead, and it works great! Very much appreciated!

Comment: No problem. Good luck moving forwards